# Will I still have my website wordpress theme if I transfer my website to sites like Namecheap?

Tags: themes

I have been thinking of transfering my site, but can't understand if I will still have my wordpress theme of my website?

Please help!!

Comment: This is not a WordPress development question. You may be better off targeting your question to Namecheap customer support.

Comment: If you copy your theme over yes, if you do not copy your theme over then no, but you may be a wp.com customer, in which case you need to contact their support to find out. There's not enough information to answer this question ass it's currently written, but keep in mind this stack is aimed at programmers, for general support questions you should ask at wordpress.org